# In layman's terms, what is the difference between Mac OS, Ubuntu, Linux, and Unix?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, ubuntu, operating-system

I understand that it's partly about abstraction, but since I'm a beginner, these concepts are very murky to me. Is Mac OS built on top of Linux architecture? How does Linux relate to Unix/Ubuntu? I've tried researching this elsewhere, but hard to find a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix is an operating system originally developed in the 1970s, on which Mac OS X is based. Linux is a kernel (the part of an operating system which interfaces with the hardware), while distributions such as Ubuntu or Fedora add the rest of the software (much of which comes from the GNU project) to make it into a full OS. Linux and the GNU project originally came to exist to provide a free alternative to the closed-source Unix, so while the code is not descended from Unix, they are quite similar.

Answer (score 3):

Linux is an operating system kernel only, it is compliant with Unix standards. A kernel is the minimum running software component in a modern operating system that handles the execution of programs, manages hardware, memory, IO, and so on. It is not something a regular user interacts with directly, or is even aware of.

Ubuntu is a complete operating system that uses the Linux kernel. A complete operating system includes programs (web browser, file explorer, photo viewer, printer driver, desktop environment, things like that) and provides a complete user interface. Since it runs the Linux kernel, it is compliant with Unix standards.

Unix is the general name given to the operating system kernel as well the userspace utilities and the standards originally developed in the 1970s.

Mac OS is a complete operating system that runs the Darwin kernel and the FreeBSD userspace utilities, and is compliant with Unix standards.

This means that a program written in C that complies to the POSIX/Single UNIX specification (set of operating system standards) will compile and work the same way on Linux, Mac OS, FreeBSD, etc. Note that Windows is the odd operating system that is NOT POSIX/Single UNIX compliant and is very different from the above mentioned operating systems and will not necessarily be able to run that  program without major modifications.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are ["Unix Like"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems.

Ubuntu is a [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux). It runs a [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (and so does [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)).

[Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) does not exist today as a concrete operating system.... Except as an archetype, and that archetype was [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) (Posix is a standard specification, not an existing software), and is now [OpenGroup Unix](http://www.unix.org/) (which is also a standard specification).

<sup>the old ATT Unix code is legally nearly lost to SCO which is bankrupt.</sup>

All of the systems you list are implementing Posix.

So a Posix-conforming C program would be easily portable from one to another -you probably would just need to recompile it.

Comment: I'm sorry this is not correct. UNIX does still exist. and is a certifiable standard beyond POSIX. the current UNIX certification is UNIX 03 or ISO 9945:2003 products currently under the UNIX 03 certification are OS X 10.8, Solaris 10 and 11, AIX 5L and 6, HP-UX B.11.31, and Inspur K-UX 2.0

Comment: Unix was bought by SCO, which get bankrupt....

Comment: tell that to the open group which is who owns the standard [not the source code that SCO bought]

Answer (score 0):

Unix is an operating system developed in the 70s along side the C programming language. The UNIX paradigm has had a profound influence on every operating system developed since, elements of it can be found even in Windows.

Several operating systems have been created which follow the Unix paradigm. Mac OS has a kernel that is based on one of the first version of Unix made for PC, called BSD Unix.

Linux started out as a hobbyist operating system which has since become a very professional operating system. As the name indicates it also follows the Unix paradigm. This means that in general a program that compiles on Unix will compile on Linux and MacOS.

Many open source operating systems have something called distributions, so there are distributions of Linux and BSD. These distributions are essentially just a set of pre-configured software, but with effort you could just assemble the same thing yourself from scratch. Ubuntu is one such distribution.

Because of the various UNIX-like operating systems, the Unix C API has been standardized under the name Posix.    Most operating systems natively support Posix. Microsoft offers a Posix layer for Windows as well.